# Running Android projects in Eclipse has error: An internal error occurred during: "Launching InsideCarolina2". com/android/ddmlib/InstallException

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse flipped out, and now will not run any of my Android projects, all of which were working fine before.

If I try to right click and run as Android project, nothing happens. If I go to properties of the project and go to run/debug settings and try to create a new one, I get an error dialog that says

```
'Update LCD' has encountered a problem. An internal error has occured.
```

The details show:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching InsideCarolina2".
com/android/ddmlib/InstallException
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the android 2.3 sdk (platform 9) and got the same error. I just updated the android ddms plugin through the eclipse software update menu and it resolved the problem!

Comment: I didn't update the SDK at all, but I ended up resolving it by deleting Eclipse and getting a fresh copy.

Comment: That probably broke something else.. Generally, deleting things leaves open ended code bits in and around the platform depending on your plugins and updates. You should always try to fix first. Like making sure everything is updated. You shloud try updating now, to make sure your able to manage your dev env.